# Class Binding ternary operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some rather cumbersome logic I would like to apply to an element class.

```
:class="{sportTypes.sports.indexOf(sport) > -1 ? 'is-primary' : 'is-outlined'}"
```

The above doesn't work, while the following does:

```
:class="{'is-outlined': sportTypes.sports.indexOf(sport) > -1}"
```

I get the following error

```
template syntax error - invalid expression:
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the first part?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have unnecessary braces. The latter expression is an object whereas the first is simply a ternary expression that returns a string.

```
:class="sportTypes.sports.indexOf(sport) > -1 ? 'is-primary' : 'is-outlined'"
```

Comment: what if i want change the last class 'progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-secondary'    if condtion is true change bg-primary if false stay bg-secondary ?

Comment: @FreddySidauruk that sounds worthy of its own question as it would be too difficult to get all the details via comments

Answer (score 6):

As par the syntax given in the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax), you can use following array syntax to achieve this:

```
:class="[sportTypes.sports.indexOf(sport) > -1 ? 'is-primary' : 'is-outlined']"
```

Answer (score 5):

When you're applying class bindings in `Vue`, you only use braces for object style assignments like in your second statement. For single bindings you just do...

```
:class="sportTypes.sports.indexOf(sport) > -1 ? 'is-primary' : 'is-outlined'"
```

and if you wanted to apply multiple bindings in the same logical statement, you surround them in `[]` instead of `{}` and separate by commas.